# Anyone know any good backend user online file manager?

Tags: php, apache, file-management

I'm looking for a backend system where your clients can login and upload files to your server, download files from the server and you can delete the users, create users, etc. I do not know the proper name for this kind of software. Maybe its called online file manager? Any recommendations? My server supports PHP, apache and mysq.

Comment: i remember spending an hour or 2 trying to find one, but was disappointed in the lack of selection. It looks like there are some good solutions from this.

Answer (score 3):

I tested [Mollify](http://www.mollify.org/) (PHP-based) and found it to be quite good.

Answer (score 2):

Shameless plug: I once created [myftphp](http://myftphp.sourceforge.net). it's a file manager written in php, which manages several users in distinct home directories. maybe you can give it a shot

Answer (score 2):

You can also look at FileGator (http://file-gator.com) It has very advanced features like multiuser with permissions and home dir for each user, ajax multifile upload, drag&drop, zip, unzip, image gallery, sending email links, directory tree, edit files...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should have a look at [IMCE](http://ufku.com/drupal/imce), it is quite simple

For something more complex try this:
http://drupal.org/project/webfm

Notice the column regarding "related projects"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, the ASP.NET file manager HTTP Commander is what you need:
http://www.element-it.com/asp-net-explorer-browser/online-share/web-file-manager.aspx. I like it a lot 'cause it allows upload and download files and edit them online. Also it supports Active Directory users, groups and their home folders. As admin you may manage users. Users may work with remote files and rich features of editing office documents online(MS office, OpenOffice and Google Docs integration). I hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am literally doing the same thing right now.

Personally, I would cook my own up, as it usually needs to be integrated into your existing structure or application.

Give me some background information. What is this for exactly? How complex does it have to be? Is it being integrated into another application or is it a stand-alone? How experienced are you with php?

#### Edit

Hmmm, for a full management suite you might want to have a look at a for-sale solution. Something higher grade will save you tons of time in development and integration. A couple that I thought were pretty good:

http://www.filerun.com/ (Very slick but expensive)

http://www.solitude.dk/filethingie/ (Free for personal use and cheap for business)

Comment: Well, it should allow me to create users, folders, delete, upload, download files. As for clients, they can only access folders that are set by me, upload files, download files and view videos or jpg.